# Форматирование текста в WebView

Tags: java, android

Сервер возвращает html разметку, я её пропускаю через TextUtils.htmlEncode

Вопрос, как отформатировать текст дальше?

Либо Encoder лишний и следуют сразу отправлять этот текст в webView?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Encoder лишний.
Вообще если вы хотите отобразить только кусок разметки, а не полноценную html страницу, то можно использовать `TextView`:

```
myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<h2>Title</h2><br><p>Description here</p>"));
```

Comment: Помогло, спасибо

Comment: Хотелось бы заметить, что данный метод начиная с `API level 24` `deprecated` и по-хорошему нужно в зависимости от версии пользоваться либо этим методом, либо новым.

Comment: @post_zeew согласен, надо. Но документация умалчивает о том что же это за флаги такие надо использовать.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml(java.lang.String, int)

Comment: @lllyct, На странице, на которую Вы привели ссылку, расписаны значения флагов.

Comment: @post_zeew вы правы, я невнимательный. Не готов редактировать ответ, т.к. не уверен какой именно флаг использовать.